# Selenium Grid -- Hub and Node performance issue

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, selenium-server, selenium-hub

I am trying to run Selenium Grid.

Currently, I'm using v3.8.1 with one hub on 1 network and 20+ nodes of different networks registering to that Selenium hub.

It's executing fast when hub and node are created on the same machine where the application has deployed. Nodes created in other remote machines are **comparatively slow**.

Slow when we try to access particular Node by passing applicationName in capability instead of HUB selecting the node randomly.

**More Info:** 
Windows server 2008, Ruby gem - selenium-webdriver-2.53.4, selenium-server-standalone-3.8.1, Java 8.

Tried Selenium Grid versions - 2.48, 2.49, 2.52, 2.53 and 3.8.1 as per https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/1565.

Any help on this is appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Any data/statistics on `comparatively slow`? Compared to ?

Comment: @DebanjanB For 100 test steps execution, the node with in the application server machine takes **3 min 30 sec** but node in other rdps takes **5 min 30 secs**.

Comment: Did you consider for the _Network Latency_?

Comment: Yes, I tested on network latency.  I tried creating Node on same network machine but still took same time as other network rdps.

Answer (score 0):

At last I got it. Its not a selenium node performance issue. 
Its a rdp performance issue as it has shared resources.

Its working fine in individual VMs and in server machine.

Thanks You.